# Migrating RedShift to different AWS Account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm migrating a RedShift data warehouse from a legacy vpc, in an AWS account that will be decommissioned, to another AWS account within the same AWS Organization.

I've done some initial reading and research into this task but have only found a solution of RedShift cross-account replication/access and/or taking a snapshot of the RedShift cluster and making that snapshot available in the new account and restoring from there.

Are there any other ways to successfully migrate an AWS RedShift from one account to another?

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with using the Snapshot method?

Comment: Well, I don't think anything is wrong with the snapshot method...I was just curious if that is the recommended migration method or if anyone has had success in migrating any other way.

Comment: Using a snapshot will give an exact copy of the data. However, it does require down-time. Doing 'live' migrations can be less-than-perfect because things can always be missed.